# How to hook local state update from global context change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I try to propagate global React context change into a sub component local state.

I need to use updated context value in the sub component for local filtering and various data transformation, but without altering the global context data.

A minimal example is available here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/contexttostate-z1svj

Context value correctly triggers component rendering on each change, but I cannot figure out how to use this change in a local effect hook.

Comment: I have exactly the same challenge. Curious why this attracted no solutions.